# How can i set Height of navigation <div> same as height of circle <div> without hardcoding any value

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a fiddle,

https://jsfiddle.net/thakv1/9zf1tm7q/2/

HTML :-

```
<div class = "single-page">
  <div class="navigation">
    <div class ="circle">
      1
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:-

```
.single-page{
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
}
.content{
  height: 400px;
  flex:1;
  background-color:white;
}
.navigation{
  width : 52px;
}
.circle{
    width: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #295ED9;
    color: white;
    font-weight: 700;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 20px 10px;
}
```

In this fiddle the height of navigation  is 400px, i want height of navigation equal to height of circle div (around 30px something) not content div.How can we achieve this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should add `align-self:flex-start` to `.navigation`

```css
.single-page{
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
}
.content{
  height: 400px;
  flex:1;
  background-color:red;
}
.navigation{
  width : 52px;
  background: red;
  align-self:flex-start;
}
.circle{
    width: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #295ED9;
    color: white;
    font-weight: 700;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 20px 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class = "single-page">
  <div class="navigation">
    <div class ="circle">
      1
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: nice solution,but how did do find out cause i am not able to think in any way.Also can u explain(maybe it is simple but i am not able to think of such fixes).